# Where to find a place to publish a specific kind of work?

Tags: publishing

I've written some stories about my adventures in the wars.  I don't think they're Hemingway caliber, but I don't think they're bad.  They're non-fiction and I am careful not to embellish for the sake of entertainment, so maybe mostly people with a similar background would find them appealing?

Anyway, since they're not short fiction stories, which is what most sites / magazines seem to publish, I don't really know where to look.  Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you attempting to make money? If not, the VA has volunteer opportunities for inspirational speakers, and you could sell or donate a few signed books here and there (and take the tax break for any publishing costs given as donations).

Answer (score 1):

You could always consider self-publishing your work. Whether your stories are a collection of individual tales pertaining to different incidents or a continuous timeline of events, I'm sure you would be able to find an audience. If you aren't familiar with what is required to self-publish, I would recommend visiting a forum where writers discuss the steps they have taken. One that I frequent quite often is the [Writer's Café](http://www.kboards.com/index.php?board=60.0), which is part of the Kindle Boards community. You can find several authors there who can help answer questions and provide guidance on what you need to get you going.

Probably the easiest place to submit your work would be [Kindle Direct Publishing](https://kdp.amazon.com/), where you can make your work available in e-book format. Amazon basically provides the sales platform for you, so all you have to do is promote the book. You can also make your book available in print by using [CreateSpace](https://www.createspace.com/), which is Amazon's print distribution model for self-publishers.

If you're interested in going through a traditional publishing house, then I would suggest considering a monthly subscription to the [Writer's Market](http://www.writersmarket.com/), which will provide you with a list of publishers and agents along with their submission guidelines. This would be a quick and simple means of identifying potential publishers that you could consider submitting your work to, but it would involve more time and effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

First, figure out the bare-bones general description of what you've written. From what you've said, I assume it would classify them Non-fiction military short stories.

I hit Google with 'non fiction military short story', and got the following links on the first page: Goodreads 'most popular military non-fiction' and Goodreads 'best modern day military accounts', 'How To Write A Story That MEA Will Publish' at  militaryexperience.org, and 'Nonfiction Short Stories - 3:AM Magazine' at3ammagazine.com (along with a few other less helpful links). Try some similar searches, such as substituting 'army' (or whatever branch you served in) instead of 'military', adding 'magazine' if that's the kind of publisher you want, etc.

If you are looking for potential publishers for a book (a collection of short stories), try looking for books that are the same kind of non-embellished military non-fiction short story collections, on Goodreads, Amazon, Barnes & Noble, etc., and see if there are any books in that niche. If so, see who published them: you now have the name of a publisher that prints that kind of book.

And thank you for your service!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider putting them on [Medium](http://medium.com/). It is basically a magazine that anyone can contribute to. You tag your stories with keywords, and Medium readers *follow* keywords in the same way you can *follow* users on Twitter. For example, there may be readers following every article tagged “war.” So tagging your work should be done with great care, because you are basically choosing what section of the magazine your work belongs in, and which readers — interested or disinterested — see your work. Investigate exactly which tags apply to your work.

Other magazine editors also look at Medium for articles to syndicate to their sites. So it can be a way to get started publishing in other contexts.