# How and where to publish my first poem / story?

Tags: publishing, poetry

I have written poems and short stories and want to publish somewhere. but I am not aware about how to publish it so that it can reach to max people. Please suggest a way to do so.

thanks.!

Comment: @what, what you say does not help Krishna in any way. Krishna Datt Shukla, you should clarify your point here - do you want to publish it as a paper book, or an e book, or just to put it somewhere in the web. Have a look at "Smashwords" (https://www.smashwords.com/). There you can publish and choose if you want to put price or publish for free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/711/5645 + http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/24655/5645 + http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/8704/5645 + http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/21128/5645 + http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/25576/5645 + http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/4855/5645 + http://writers.stackexchange.com/q/5051/5645

Comment: @what Well I don't fully agree. I mean I mostly read popular novels and classics which began as paperbacks but this does not answer the question where can I publish my works. I mean I might want to publish them in my blog for example.

Comment: Try wordpress.com.  It's free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google literary magazines. There are some online but your best bet is to look for ones in your own country or close by as they like local flavour. They often pay out as well if they pick your poem or short story.

Anthologies is the next best bet. Either gather together a few of your own poems and short stories and publish them as an Anthology or see if there are other writers interested in putting together an Anthology together.

If you don't mind giving them away free then there are also sites that publish e-stories and e-poems. Best to find one that suits your writing. Like Wattpad if you are writing teenage fiction. There is a place for every kind of writing.